# Send Friend Request from my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I want that i have a business portal any one enter in my portal get a send friend request button with in my website when the user of my website click the button automatically send the friend request to me. It can be possible?
give me some code on java script

Comment: For a “business portal” you should not be using a user profile anyway, but a page. And then you have the option of embedding f.e. the Like Button or the Page Plugin.